# Do we assume Tense head for tenseless languages?

Tags: syntax-trees, tense

Do we assume a TP/IP projection for the syntax of a tenseless language?

Comment: I don't know what other syntacticians would say, but I'd suggest the assumption of a TP is just another sign of Anglocentrism in linguistics. Aspect and modality prominent languages should have AP and MP phrases respectively.

Comment: @curiousdannii why do we need to posit the existance of separate categories for those, if those languages all do not treat tense as prominently?

Comment: @curiousdannii - English could be considered to have MP and AP too, but T, A, and M are all closed-class (so easy to pack together).  English storytelling can slip into tenselessness, once tense has been established (adverbially).

Comment: @curiousdannii One of my concerns is that [Spec, TP] is the position for the Subject at S-representation, so for a tenseless language, we need to assume another position for the subject if we don't assume a TP. If so, this doesn't entertain the idea of universal grammar.

Comment: @Terry_Clem Why not simply replace the TP with an AP or MP depending on what is more prominent? The dominant prominence of a language can be considered a parameter, so this approach would be fully compatible with universal grammar IMO.